# connection from access vba to odbc table

Tags: sql-server, vba, connection

I use the code below to connect to a sql server table

```
Dim Cn1 As New ADODB.Connection

Dim Rs1 As New ADODB.Recordset

Cn1.Open "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;DATABASE=\\\s100nlex\DATA\SQL Database.mdf", "Erik", "Passwd"
Rs1.Open "SELECT [ODBC Table].* FROM [ODBC Table];", Cn1
```

I can open the ODBC Table manually but get an error on the `Cn1.open...`. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify the mdf file for SQL Server connections, you need to specify a server and a database:

```
Cn1.Open "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=s100nlex;DATABASE=DatabaseName", "Erik", "Passwd"
```